# Google Sheets; QUERY

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BEcjQ9MbKIKHqtLGH8hRPuovJFXWGh6EerbOFZJftnw/edit?usp=sharing)
Good afternoon.
Please help me complete the QUERY formula
When choosing a check box, data from two sheets was selected.

I've tried different options and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following formula in Data!G1.

```
={QUERY(Sheet1!A1:E6;"where E=true";1);
  QUERY(Sheet2!A1:E6;"where E=true";0)}
```

Used a Array Literal with separate Query formulas for each sheet.
It works because the two data sets use the same number of columns and headings; the second set of headings does not populate because it is treated as a row of data and Column E is not TRUE.